# Use multiple SASS files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

I want to separate my (giant) global css file into multiple files.  I'm using sass. Is there an easy way to get sass to watch multiple files?  I think I could use @import, but just wanted to know if there was another (better) way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Watch files: `sass --watch public/stylesheets/sass:public/stylesheets`. That will monitor all `.scss` files in `public/stylesheets/sass` and write them out as `.css` to `public/stylesheets/`

Comment: I think this is actually the best solution because it allows for separate CSS files.  Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What **Rich Bradshaw** mentions is correct, however here is another approach that you *could* take.

Create 1 scss file called `combined.scss` *(for example)* then inside of this file `@import` all your scss files, then simply run `sass --style compressed --watch combined.scss:combined.css` and it will detect changes to the imported scss files and recompile as needed.

`Combined.scss` example:

```
@import "reset";
@import "layout";
@import "styles";
@import "ie";
```

So when you make a change to the `layout.scss` file `combined.scss` will recompile and all your actual html pages will need to reference is `combined.css`.

But like I said, **Rich Bradshaw**'s solution will work just as well and depending on the project you're working on might be better to use.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. One little thing I forgot to mention is that `@mixins` are only available to a file if your reference them directly. So if you were to create a separate file just for your `mixins` then make sure that every file that needs access to it has an `@import "mixin";` as its first line (eg in `layout.scss` and in `styles.scss`).

Comment: One additional note: when you prefix your additional stylesheets with an underscore (e.g. "_reset.scss"), Sass will not compile them to css. If you include them with `@import "reset.scss` (underscore can be left out here) in your combined.scss then only combined.scss will be compiled, even when some of the included scss-files changed.

Answer (score 9):

I use import, then go to my media directory, which includes a directory called css with all my css in and run `sass --style compressed --watch css:css`. That produces one css file from loads of scss files.

To clarify this, if you name your imported files starting with an underscore, then SASS doesn't try to compile those.

So, if you have a file called style.scss containing these lines,

```
@import 'reset';
@import 'blog';
```

and some files called _reset.scss and _blog.scss will mean that when you run the command above it produces one file called style.css that contains all the other files. Variables declared higher up work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the filename beginning with underscores, I didn't remember this and it was what I was looking for !

Comment: one thing... "The underscore just tells Sass not to create a CSS file when it does its compiling. It doesn't mean "hey, totally ignore the contents of this file all together." – @cimmanon in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323220/sasssyntaxerror-undefined-variable