# Sass::SyntaxError Undefined Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm new to the Asset Pipeline, so let me know if I'm doing things wrong.

Using Rails 3.2 with SASS.  I have a configuration partial that defines a bunch of SASS variables that I want to use throughout my scss files.  Per [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), I import `configuration` first, then `bonus`.  However, I keep getting a `Sass::SyntaxError` saying `Undefined variable: "$darkRed"` in bonus.css.scss.  What am I doing wrong?

application.css.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*/

@import "configuration";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bonus";
```

_configuration.css.scss

```
//colors
$darkRed: #B94A48;
$controlColor: #777;
```

bonus.css.scss

```
div.give-inline-help .help-inline
  {
  color: $darkRed;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: MuseoSans-300;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This is a 3+ year old question...and you're marking it as duplicate now?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You import scss file with wrong name in `application.css.scss`:

replace: `@import "configuration";`

with: `@import "_configuration";`

or rename your `_configuration.css.scss` file to `configuration.css.scss`

Comment: Is this something Rails specific?  Because "configuration" and "_configuration" are interchangeable in Sass outside of Rails.

Comment: Take a look a this [Multiple SASS file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571477/use-multiple-sass-files): "if you name your imported files starting with an underscore, then SASS doesn't try to compile those."

Comment: You're misunderstanding what that means.  The underscore just tells Sass not to create a CSS file when it does its compiling.  It doesn't mean "hey, totally ignore the contents of this file all together."

Comment: I tried this and got this error `File to import not found or unreadable`

Answer (score 2):

So I bumped into this and wanted to give a more precise answer:

Any `@import`ed file in the chain downstream from a *non-underscore* named file will break with `Sass::SyntaxError Undefined Variable`.

With Sass, if you want to override variables, you must ensure you use an uninterrupted chain of underscored files.

It's as simple as that, though sometimes very easy to pass by!

Comment: Is there no dry way to include those definitions down-stream?

Comment: @jwg2s - simply keeping the top level a non-underscore, and everything else prefixed with the underscore solves the issue.  It kind of makes sense now, any non-underscored file has it's own discrete scope, while an underscored file belongs to another's scope.