# Sass::SyntaxError Undefined Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

There are already a plethora of questions on how to resolve the above error message.

The one with the best answers seems to be [Sass::SyntaxError Undefined Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323220/sasssyntaxerror-undefined-variable/34788783?noredirect=1), which unfortunately is quite old already.

My current (works on Rails 4.2) solution to the problem is to `@include` a file called `_variables.sass` from every other `.sass` file that needs to make use of the variables such as `color` values or `font-family` definitions. It would, however, be much more convenient if the `_variables.sass` file could be `@import`ed once from within `application.sass` (before anything else of course).

All of my attempts at accomplishing this, including using only file names starting with an underscore, have failed. My question is thus if anybody knows how to achieve SASS variables in one file being available to multiple other files with central `@import` statements in `application.sass` on Rails 4.2?

Here's proof of error message with the above described setup.
Files:

```
$ ls app/assets/stylesheets/
application.sass  _foundation_and_overrides.sass  _list_defaults.sass  _phrases.sass   _translations.sass   _users.sass
_bidi.sass        _layout.sass                    _pages.sass          _searches.sass  _user_sessions.sass  _variables.sass
```

application.sass:

```
$ cat app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass 
// @import 'list_defaults'

// @import 'font-awesome'

@import '_variables'
@import '_foundation_and_overrides'
@import '_bidi'
@import '_layout'
@import '_pages'
@import '_phrases'

// @import 'searches'
// @import 'translations'
// @import 'user_sessions'
// @import 'users'
```

_variables.sass:

```
$ cat app/assets/stylesheets/_variables.sass 
$white: #ffffff
$dark_white: #eaeaea
$medium_grey: #eeeeee

$very_light_red: #dbaca4
$light_red: #dc7869
$dark_red: #db1f00

$very_light_green: #b2ebd2
$light_green: #83dab3
$dark_green: #008f4e

$very_light_blue: #b1d8d9
$light_blue: #64c1c4
$dark_blue: #00868b

$font_sans: 'Open Sans', sans
$font_serif: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif
$font_arabic: 'Lateef', 'Amiri', 'Times New Roman', sans
```

_bidi.sass:

```
$ cat app/assets/stylesheets/_bidi.sass 
// @import '_variables'

*[lang=ar],
*[lang=fa],
*[lang=ur],
*[lang=ps]
  direction: rtl
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override
  font-family: $font_arabic
*[lang=de],
*[lang=en],
*[lang=ku]
  direction: ltr
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override
```

Rake run:

```
$ rake assets:precompile 2>&1 | grep -i error
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$font_arabic".
```

Comment: @cimmanon: The answer you gave when you marked this duplicate is about Gulp, not the Rails asset pipeline.

Comment: @cimmanon Sorry to have upset you. In any case, I've added the actual code to show you that it really doesn't work.

Comment: (Also if there is anything else I should provide or if you want me to re-write the question in some way, I'd be happy to - not trying to be difficult here, just trying to get help.)

Comment: Note that I cannot reproduce an error with vanilla Sass with the information provided.

Comment: So it's got to do with Rails in some way. Of course, what else. Perhaps I should just start over from scratch with a fresh project and move stuff over piece by piece until it starts breaking...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having a very similar issue. It is almost like application.scss file is loading in reverse order rather than top to bottom for me.

Comment: Sorry @Chris, I'm still using the setup I describe in the question.